# Float Height old keihin ve17b Carb Honda GB250

Tags: carburetor, service-manual

I have a GB250 that was fitted with a racing carb. I am trying to go back to stock.

The carb I have is a keihin ve17b a Carb.

There is only a float needle and a float. The float is plastic and therefore I dont see how you would set this. The float needle has a spring inside it.

I also can not find any information on what the setting should be

Can anyone help?

Comment: Some do not have a way to adjust the float, they are designed to be at the proper level with no adjustment.